# Which homotopy types can be realized as the classifying space of a right-cancellative discrete monoid?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

McDuff [showed](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(79)90022-3) that every connected homotopy type can be realized as the classifying space of a discrete monoid, but the monoid she constructs has lots of idempotents.

**Question:** Which homotopy types are realized as the classifying space of a right-cancellative discrete monoid?

In the commutative  case, my guess would be that $BM \simeq B(M[M^{-1}])$, so that the classifying space is aspherical. But I'm less confident that this happens in the noncommutative case.

Comment: The category of elements of a semi-simplicial sets is left cancelative. So I don't know for monoid, but at least one can represent any homotopy type as the realization of a left (or right) cancelative category by taking the category of elements (or its opposite) of any semi-simplicial sets representing it.

Comment: Indeed, by subdivision one can represent any homotopy type as the classifying space of a poset, which is both left and right cancellative. But far from being a monoid.

Answer (score 5):

By universal properties,  we have that $BM$ is the classifying space of the homotopy localization $B(M[M^{-1}]^h)$.  Thus $BM$ is aspherical if and only if the homotopy localization is discrete.

Further, Dwyer-Kan showed that if $(M,W)$ admits a calculus of fractions,  then the homotopy localization agrees with the ordinary localization. When $M$ is cancellative,  $(M,M)$ admits a calculus of fractions if and only if it satisfies the Ore condition:  $$\forall m_1, m_2 \in M,  \exists n_1, n_2 \in M, ~ n_1 m_1 = n_2 m_2.$$  So in this case $M[M^{-1}]^h \simeq M[M^{-1}]$  and the homotopy localization is aspherical.  In general, I do not know what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that every cancellative commutative monoid admits a calculus of fractions, but I'm not sure I believe this in the noncommutative case; do you have  a reference? I don't see why the Ore condition should be satisfied. And for instance, having a calculus of fractions should probably imply that the monoid is embeddable in a group, which is not the case for all cancellative monoids, as I learned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup#Embeddability_in_groups).

Comment: @TimCampion I think you're right, I was misreading the Ore condition on the nLab page,  in such a way that I thought it was vacuous for the whole monoid.